# Release upgrade 22.10 to 23.04 dpkg error opera.timestamp

Tags: apt, dpkg, do-release-upgrade, opera

Some time ago i installed Opera via snap. I uninstalled it later, but since then I have problem installing new packages. I reinstalled Opera and also installed a stable deb version. This did not help, so once again I removed this. I would like now to do the release upgrade. The error I receive is:

```
readlink: missing operand
Try 'readlink --help' for more information.
stat: missing operand
Try 'stat --help' for more information.
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Problem executing scripts DPkg::Pre-Invoke 'stat -c %Z $(readlink -f $(which opera)) > /tmp/opera.timestamp', E:Sub-process returned an error code

Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewText.py", line 138, in _handleException
    apport_crash(type, value, tb)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeApport.py", line 57, in apport_crash
    apport_excepthook(type, value, tb)
TypeError: apport_excepthook() missing 1 required positional argument: 'exc_tb'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/lunar", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 241, in main
    if app.run():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2042, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1871, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.doPostInitialUpdate():
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 906, in doPostInitialUpdate
    self.quirks.run("PostInitialUpdate")
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 99, in run
    func()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 126, in lunarPostInitialUpdate
    self._maybe_prevent_flatpak_auto_removal()
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeQuirks.py", line 519, in _maybe_prevent_flatpak_auto_removal
    self.controller.cache.commit(
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-bk30gewy/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 309, in commit
    apt.Cache.commit(self, fprogress, iprogress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 668, in commit
    raise SystemError("installArchives() failed")
SystemError: installArchives() failed
```

The only topic related to this I found here: [After deleting opera browser I have E: Problem executing scripts DPkg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436884/after-deleting-opera-browser-i-have-e-problem-executing-scripts-dpkg) but this does not help. Anybody can suggest anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Talaat for trying to help.
After numerous attempts it came up that there is a folder in apt configuration.

I run
`sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99fix-opera`
and the update/upgrade proceeded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove packages that are no longer required

   sudo apt-get autoremove
2. Clean up APT cache in Ubuntu

   sudo du -sh /var/cache/apt

Either remove only the outdated packages, like those superseded by a recent update, making them completely unnecessary.

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

3. Remove older versions of Snap applications: What you have to do here is to [create a new shell script](https://linuxhandbook.com/run-shell-script/?ref=itsfoss.com) and use the following lines in your script:

   #!/bin/bash
   # Removes old revisions of snaps
   # CLOSE ALL SNAPS BEFORE RUNNING THIS
   set -eu
   snap list --all | awk '/disabled/{print $1, $3}' |
   while read snapname revision; do
   snap remove "$snapname" --revision="$revision"
   done

Give it execute permission, [run the shell script with sudo](https://itsfoss.com/run-shell-script-linux/)

4. clear temp files

Comment: I did all of that. Still receive the same error.

Comment: make sure you are typing the command ./install and not excluding the ./

Comment: tray install opera by gedpi sudo apt install gdebi
and enter the password to your computer. gdebi package installer application will be installed.Installation in ubuntu

Right click on the downloaded file and select open with “ gdebi package installer “. Then click Install Package